# How to solve error Check for integrity of file "/etc/resolv.conf" failed when run ./runcluvfy.sh?

Tags: linux, oracle

I want to install oracle database 12cR1 Real application cluster on oracle linux operating system .

I did all configurations in node 1 and node 2 but during the installation of grid infrastructure I got following errors :

```
checking DNS response from all servers in "/etc/resolv.conf"
checking response for name "kaash-his-2" from each of the name servers specified in "/etc/resolv.conf"
  Node Name     Source     Comment                   Status    
------------------------  ------------------------  ----------
checking response for name "kaash-his-1" from each of the name servers specified in "/etc/resolv.conf"
  Node Name     Source    Comment                   Status    
------------------  ------------------------  ----------

Check for integrity of file "/etc/resolv.conf" failed
```

and this is the output of file resolv.conf

```
    [root@KAASH-HIS-1 tmp]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
    # Generated by NetworkManager
    nameserver 10.93.200.222
    nameserver 10.93.200.223

   [root@KAASH-HIS-2 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
   # Generated by NetworkManager
   nameserver 10.93.200.222
   nameserver 10.93.200.223
```

the other error :

```
Starting check for /dev/shm mounted as temporary file system ...

ERROR: 

PRVE-0426 : The size of in-memory file system mounted as /dev/shm is "33554432k" megabytes which is less than the required size of "2048" megabytes on node ""
PRVE-0426 : The size of in-memory file system mounted as /dev/shm is "33554432k" megabytes which is less than the required size of "2048" megabytes on node ""

Check for /dev/shm mounted as temporary file system failed
```

and I added already the file /dev/shm in file /etc/fstab and this is the file details :

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-1 tmp]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Dec 27 13:35:34 2022
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/ol_kaash--his--1-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=8c639649-0a25-48d7-9fe5-9ed62090f457 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_kaash--his--1-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_kaash--his--1-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs size=32g 0 0
```

How to solve these errors please ?

Comment: *Where* are the servers for your RAC? Are these by any chance virtual machines running in a Cloud environment such as AWS, Azure, or something similar?

Comment: @pmdba the servers in the company I have physical servers 2 HP blade servers with shared storage

Comment: Check your firewall settings. You may need to disable the firewall on the RAC interconnect network.

Comment: @pmdba I disabled the firewall and run the fixup command also see the last errors list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of search I found the solution for these errors :

1- Edit file /etc/resolv.conf and add search and domain for all nodes :

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-1 tmp]# vi /etc/resolv.conf
    # Generated by NetworkManager
    search "local-domain-name"
    domain "local-domain-name"
    nameserver 10.93.200.222
    nameserver 10.93.200.223
```

2- about the /dev/shm size error
you can change the size and mount using the following command as root user :

```
   # mount -o remount,size=2G /dev/shm
```

then confirm the size by using

```
   # df -h
```

and during the installation you can ignore the warning if the mounted size for /dev/shm greater than 2048M